# PHP binary operator after with echo

Tags: php, debugging, echo, binary-operators

```
$DEBUG_MODE && (echo "ss");
```

Error Message Return:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in D:\HOSTS\web_portal\test.php on line 99

Can we do the about without using ?: or if? for echo or print_r etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is invalid syntax. You could use print - https://www.php.net/print

```
$DEBUG_MODE && (print('test'));
```

https://www.php.net/echo

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
> are not required to use parentheses with it

Comment: IC, I thought it is a function. THX!